# Trigger for deleting an entry right after adding it?

Tags: sql, triggers

I have the following query for creating a user account:

```
INSERT INTO [User](username, joinDate, email, password) VALUES (@name, @joinDate, @email, @password)
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[username] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[joinDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[email] [varchar](60) NULL,
[password] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,)
```

I want to make a trigger that immediately deletes everything i put into the table when the entry contains specific data.

For example if I the entry contains the username "TestUsername1234", everything that was just added should be cleared.

The reason I want to do this is for running Unit tests using the live database.

Is this possible? if so how would I do this?

Comment: Yes, using trigger it can possible in RDBMS. Specify your database in tag for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using SQL Server Database. This code will delete all the entries in the table if it has username='TestUsername1234', after each time you make an insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_InsertUserName
ON dbo.[User]
AFTER INSERT AS
DECLARE @count varchar(20)
   SELECT@count=COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE username='TestUsername1234'
   IF @COUNT>0
   BEGIN
       DELETE FROM [User];
   END
GO
```

Comment: Works! Is it also possible to have this trigger x seconds after it was input?

Comment: If you want to have a delay in execution write the delete logic inside a procedure with delay and call that procedure using INSERT trigger @FastCow